# VBScript binary array help wanted (Windows 10 1607 bug?)

Tags: arrays, vbscript, binary, byte

I have a working .vbs file which reads a binary file, changes one byte and the saves the file. Up until Windows 1607 this worked fine on many different Windows systems.

However, now with 1607 and later versions of Windows 10 it no longer works!
I have changed the code because the read file code I had no longer works correctly in 1607, but I am still having problems with the 
`data = Mid(data, 1, 21) & Chr(b21) & Mid(data, 23)` line which worked perfectly before Windows 10 1607!

I get

> (60, 3) ADODB.Stream: Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

This code creates a shortcut on the Desktop and then changes one bit of one byte so that the shortcut will be run as admin. If I comment out the offending line then it seems to work.

Is this a bug in Windows 10 1607 VBScript?

```
' Make shortcut on Desktop and Set as Run As Admin
Q = Chr(34)
Dim fso
Dim curDir
Dim WinScriptHost

If WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then 
    WScript.Echo "Please run CreateShortcuts.cmd"
    WScript.Quit
End If

' --- SET Target and Desktop Link Name from command line ---

strTargetName = WScript.Arguments.Item(0) 
strLinkName = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)

'Target - e.g.    %windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\"temp\MakePartImage_AutoRun_FAT32.cmd"

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strWinDir =WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%")
strSysDir = strWinDir & "\System32"
strMyDir = fso.GetParentFolderName(wscript.ScriptFullName) 
strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
strCurDir = WshShell.CurrentDirectory   ' e.g. C:\temp

strMyDirSpecial = Mid(strMyDir, 1, 3) & Q & Mid(strMyDir, 4) & "\" & strTargetName & Q
Set oMyShortCut= WshShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop + "\" & strLinkName)
oMyShortCut.WindowStyle = 1                              '1=default 3=max  7=Min
oMyShortCut.TargetPath = Q & strSysDir & "\cmd.exe"  & Q
oMyShortCut.Arguments=  " /c " & strMyDirSpecial
oMyShortcut.IconLocation = "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe"
oMyShortCut.WorkingDirectory = Q & strMyDir & Q
oMyShortCut.Save
Set fso = Nothing

'read binary geometry into byte array
Dim stream, data
Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
stream.Open
stream.Type = 1
stream.LoadFromFile(strDesktop + "\" & strLinkName)
data = stream.Read
stream.Close
WScript.Echo "BYTES 16-23 " & Hex(Asc(Mid(data, 16, 1))) & " " & Hex(Asc(Mid(data, 17, 1))) & " " & Hex(Asc(Mid(data, 18, 1))) & " " & Hex(Asc(Mid(data, 19, 1))) & " " & Hex(Asc(Mid(data, 20, 1))) & " " & Hex(Asc(Mid(data, 21, 1))) & " " & Hex(Asc(Mid(data, 22, 1))) & " " & Hex(Asc(Mid(data, 23, 1)))
' --- PATCH .LNK FILE to set byte 21 bit 5  for Admin rights
Dim b21
b21 = Asc(Nid(data, 22, 1)) Or 32    'set bit 6  0x20    
' THIS NEXT LINE CAUSES PROBLEMS!
data = Mid(data, 1, 21) & Chr(b21) & Mid(data, 23)
WScript.Echo "BYTES 16-23 " & Hex(Asc(Mid(data, 16, 1))) & " " & Hex(Asc(Mid(data, 17, 1))) & " " & Hex(Asc(Mid(data, 18, 1))) & " " & Hex(Asc(Mid(data, 19, 1))) & " " & Hex(Asc(Mid(data, 20, 1))) & " " & Hex(Asc(Mid(data, 21, 1))) & " " & Hex(Asc(Mid(data, 22, 1))) & " " & Hex(Asc(Mid(data, 23, 1)))

Const adTypeBinary = 1
Const adTypeText = 2
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
Dim BinaryStream
Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
BinaryStream.Type = adTypeBinary
BinaryStream.Open
BinaryStream.Write data
BinaryStream.SaveToFile strDesktop+"\" & strLinkName, adSaveCreateOverWrite

WScript.Echo "Shortcut " & strLinkName & " created on Desktop."
```

Comment: Is it the Windows OS version, the architecture  *(32 vs 64 bit)* or both that has changed?

Comment: I use Win 10 64-bit. Up until a few weeks ago it worked OK. Now it does not work. Another user said it was 1607 update and also latest pre-release update which both show a problem. My version is now 1607 and it no longer works so I assume it is bug in 1607.

Comment: It fails on 1607 Build 14303.3.969.
I tried a fresh install of Win 10 1607 Build 14393.3.0  and the vbscript works. So problem is caused by late KB update?

Comment: If that fixed it without any modifications to the code, then you'd be best leaving an answer. Don't worry [so] [encourages answering your own questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), it doesn't go against you and this might help someone else who encounters the same issue.

Comment: I updated to 14303.3.969 from 14303.3.0 and now the same vbscript fails!
So KB4015438 has broken vbscript!!!

Comment: For a quick test, download the MPI Tool Kit v.0.72 from https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqlrQcdsFA-Kmiz7nSXLGNMWMuT2 - unzip it to a folder on the Desktop and double-click CreateDesktopShortcuts.cmd - this should create 3 shortcuts on the Desktop (which you can easily delete later). The vbscript which does this does not work on 14303.3.969 but it does work on 14303.3.0

Comment: Win 10 1703 Build 15063.0 also has same issue with VBScript

Answer (score 0):

```
' THIS NEXT LINE CAUSES PROBLEMS!
data = Mid(data, 1, 21) & Chr(b21) & Mid(data, 23)
```

This line causes problems because it changes the type of data from Byte() to String. This would illustrate it:

```
WScript.Echo TypeName(data)
' THIS NEXT LINE CAUSES PROBLEMS!
data = Mid(data, 1, 21) & Chr(b21) & Mid(data, 23)
WScript.Echo TypeName(data)
```

ADODB Stream.Write function only accepts Byte() arrays.

The solution is to use this function from motobit website:

```
' http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_binarytostring/
Function MultiByteToBinary(MultiByte)
  '� 2000 Antonin Foller, http://www.motobit.com
  ' MultiByteToBinary converts multibyte string To real binary data (VT_UI1 | VT_ARRAY)
  ' Using recordset
  Dim RS, LMultiByte, Binary
  Const adLongVarBinary = 205
  Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  LMultiByte = LenB(MultiByte)
  If LMultiByte>0 Then
    RS.Fields.Append "mBinary", adLongVarBinary, LMultiByte
    RS.Open
    RS.AddNew
      RS("mBinary").AppendChunk MultiByte & ChrB(0)
    RS.Update
    Binary = RS("mBinary").GetChunk(LMultiByte)
  End If
  MultiByteToBinary = Binary
End Function
```

But the string needs to be converted to multi-byte first. For this purpose there is another function:

```
' http://www.motobit.com/help/regedit/pa26.htm
'Converts unicode string to a multibyte string
Function StringToMB(S)
  Dim I, B
  For I = 1 To Len(S)
    B = B & ChrB(Asc(Mid(S, I, 1)))
  Next
  StringToMB = B
End Function
```

So, this is how to make it work:

```
data = Mid(data, 1, 21) & Chr(b21) & Mid(data, 23)
data = MultiByteToBinary(StringToMB(data))
```